# Is there any other way to add " delimiter to 1 row dataframe in looping for multiple CSV files?

Tags: python, string, csv, postman, delimiter

(I'd like to apologize beforehand for lacking in English and python)

I have 120066 CSV files in a folder, which all has similar structure: 2 columns (itemID, and itemName) with 900 rows of values. The itemID is an int64 (it is a long integer, which I have a trouble to load it into a Postman runner), and the itemName is a string.

I need to do a request through Postman runner, importing each CSV whenever needed. But the column 'itemID' is not read properly. Turns out that Postman parse CSV files with json limitation so the long integer get rounded.

So I think maybe I need to insert " delimiter to all of my CSV files, but I don't know how because python doesn't keep " delimiter written in the CSV. I tried this:

```
import pandas
for file_number in range (120066):
    file_name = f'datasets/filtered/itemset181020_{file_number}.csv'
    file_write = f'datasets/string/stringfiltered_{file_number}.csv'
    df = pandas.read_csv(file_name, sep=',', usecols=['itemID'])
    df['itemID'] = df['itemID'].to_string(index=False)
    df.to_csv(file_write, index=False, mode='w')
```

But the output CSV looks like this:

`itemID`

`"1213330173736738817 1214195710301618178 1214198629553950721 ... 1215908513064607745"`

And when I import(?) the CSV to my Postman runner, its preview is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGO2Z.png)

Is there any other way for me to add " delimiter to these CSVs? I've also tried apply(), astype(), convert_dtype(), map() but also didn't work :( thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

okay so maybe some people are just as clueless as me. So apparently it's okay to use .astype(), the problem is just that I need to set the quoting parameter in .to_csv()

so I need to change these 2 lines of the code

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, usecols=['itemID']).astype('string')
df.to_csv(file_write, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```